# CMake. How to generate Visual Studo solution with different libary types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

There is CMake script for C++ project with following content:

```
#...

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug_static")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release_static")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

#...
```

Library type depends on build type. When I build project with CMake everything is ok, but i can't generate equivalent VS solution.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

I run CMake without `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` => all `if`-s is `FALSE` => no target - no soution.

When I set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug_static -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

all 4 configurations will be like `Debug_static`. I think for this case [generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)) was invented, but `add_library` doesn't support them for library type.

**So, my question is:** How to change my CMake script to make VS generator able to generate equivalent solution? 4 configurations: 2 shared and 2 static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) :

> This variable is only meaningful to single-configuration generators...

To add customize configurations for multi-configuration generator you have to set [CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.html).

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Release Debug Release_static Debug_static)
```

Then for each new configuration type (Release_static and Debug_static) set the compiler and linker variables needed for your project.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_STATIC ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE_STATIC ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE})
...
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_STATIC ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
...
```

As far as I know it is not possible to add single-configuration target for multi-configuration generator output. So just add separate targets for shared and static libraries.

To avoid building both libraries for any configuration set [EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_CONFIG](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_CONFIG.html) properties.

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_RELEASE_STATIC TRUE
    EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_DEBUG_STATIC TRUE)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_static STATIC ${SRC_FILES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES
    EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_RELEASE TRUE
    EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_DEBUG TRUE)
```

Building solution will compile only library matching active configuration.

Use [OUTPUT_NAME](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) to make *${PROJECT_NAME}_static* target produce *${PROJECT_NAME}*.lib at output.

I hope it's close enough to your scenario.